# parsing json 2 arrays (embbeded ) in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I'm trying to find the **value** in jsonObject **distance** (which is 10194)

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Burnaby, BC, Canada" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Vancouver, BC, Canada" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "10.2 km",
                  "value" : 10194
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "19 mins",
                  "value" : 1118
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I wrote this code but it gives me null

```
  rows = jObj.getJSONObject(TAG_ROWS);
       JSONArray elements = new JSONArray (rows.getString(TAG_ELEMENTS));
       for (int i=0; i<elements.length();i++){
            JSONObject obj = elements.optJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject distance = obj.getJSONObject(TAG_DISTANCE);
             value= distance.getString(TAG_VALUE);
```

any idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gonna have to do something as below

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(YOUR-JSON-STRING-HERE);

    String destination = jsonObj.getString("destination_addresses");
    // printing the destination and checking wheather parsed correctly
    Log.v("Destination", destination);

    JSONArray jarRow = jsonObj.getJSONArray("rows");
    for(int i=0;i<jarRow.length(); i++){
        // creating an object first
        JSONObject ElementsObj = jarRow.getJSONObject(i);
        // and getting the array out of the object
        JSONArray jarElements = ElementsObj.getJSONArray("elements");
        for(int j=0; j<jarElements.length(); j++){
            JSONObject distanceObj = jarElements.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("distance");
            String distanceStr = distanceObj.getString("value");
            Log.v("finally getting distance : ", distanceStr);
        }
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

here is a screen shot from **DDMS**

[image]

Comment: thank you itself telling me how much frustration you had. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your `JSON`, even `rows` is of the type `JSONArray`, but you're fetching rows, this way

```
rows = jObj.getJSONObject(TAG_ROWS);
```

Hence, the problem.

You need to fetch `rows` like this:-

```
JSONArray rows = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ROWS);
```

Answer (score 0):

The object 'rows' must be typed JSONArray since what it contains is an array. After that you must do another for and get the other array that is 'elements' and then do the loop for the second array. You must get something like:

```
rows = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ROWS);
 for (int i=0; i<rows.length();i++){
       JSONArray elements = new JSONArray (rows.getString(TAG_ELEMENTS));
       for (int j=0; j<elements.length();j++){
            JSONObject obj = elements.optJSONObject(j);
            JSONObject distance = obj.getJSONObject(TAG_DISTANCE);
             value= distance.getString(TAG_VALUE);
       }
 }
```